# ¿Como desactivar vista previa en Google Chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, impresión

Un gusto saludarles, deseo hacerles la siguiente pregunta:

Resulta que deseo imprimir directamente a una impresora predeterminada en  **Google Chrome**, he intentado hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

En el acceso directo de google chrome,le añado a la dirección  **-- disable-print-preview**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando lo pruebo, le pongo aplicar y luego aceptar. Pero al probar, no funciona, sigue apareciendo la vista previa. He podido des-habilitar en el **Mozilla**, pero aquí no.

Tengo `Windows 7 profesional de 64 bits` y `Google Chrome versión 60.0.3112.113`(en agosto fue la ultima actualización, me imagino que será la misma que tendrán ustedes.)

Espero poder encontrar una solución, yo se que todo en la vida es posible.
Saludos.

Comment: Lee la [respuesta aceptada aquí](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/JJNzUxxtMio;context-place=topicsearchin/chrome/authorid$3AAPn2wQc4XjuNw-oPI5lS5yG8xTAhhKQcDhY7WrvITSksnbovCjaQnH6G74ez-CiBTNEEZw22ybgr%7Csort:date%7Cspell:false).

Comment: gracias@MauricioAriasOlave, hice la prueba, pero no tuve éxito, sigue apareciéndome la vista previa. Igual hay que tener en cuenta que esa solución fue para el 2014, y la versión del google chrome ha ido cambiando

Comment: Danilo, ok, lo agregué porque supuse que hiciste las pruebas pero sin haber cerrado las ventanas de Chrome y/o Chrome aún estaba corriendo "en el administrador de tareas".

Comment: Tuve que reiniciar el pc para que los cambios tuvieran exito, pero hay detalle que no es menor, el cual no aparece la barra de navegación y las pestañas abiertas, para ser mas especifico tiene el efecto cuando uno apreta F11 en el navegador, pero de forma permanente.

Answer (score 1):

Por seguridad no se puede. Imagínate una web maliciosa que te quiere imprimir 2000 hojas de texto de su publicidad, como no hay que aceptar nada, pues se imprimirán y es un problema.

El modo kiosco, esta pensado para las típicas máquinas de autoservicio, lamentablemente esta opción solo permite imprimir en etiquetatodar en formato RAW y térmicas, como la zebra.

Para poder implementar lo que pides necesitas un printserver que no es ni fácil ni gratis, pero esto ya se sale de tu pregunta.

Espero ser de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

probaste la combinación de teclas Ctrl+Mayús+P? o también añade --kiosk --kiosk-printing a las propiedades del acceso directo, en Destino. Quedaría así:

"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk --kiosk-printing

Saludos, espero sirva de algo.

Comment: No me resulta, todos dicen que por seguridad no se puede hacer aplicaciones que imprima directo, pero yo he visto que desde google crome imprimen sin vista previa.